# How Kendo distribute the empty spaces or How kendo set the width when the width is dynamic

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Created a Grid using Kendo MVC Grid. I haven't added any fixed column width and Kendo is adjusting the column width based on the content/header length. But the spacing between the columns are not consistent.

I would like to know that how the Kendo distributing the empty spaces? Or how Kendo distribute the column widths.

I'm trying understand more about the empty space distribution on Grids.

Thanks You!

[image]

Comment: You can use a percentage. that the tool itself does with respect to the size of division.

Comment: I don't want to give any width(percentage/fixed). I just want to distribute empty spaces equally to all columns.